# Copy Files From Flash Drive To Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cp

I am attempting to copy files from my flash drive to my local drive on Ubuntu.  This is the command that I ran

```
sudo cp -i  /media/owner/ESD-USB/mysql /var/lib/
```

But that output a message of - and the files were not copied over (replacing the original files)

```
cp: omitting directory '/media/owner/ESD-USB/mysql'
```

What do I need to do in order to copy this directory from my flash drive and over write the current directory on my hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give directory as source argument and expect `cp` to copy the files. To do this, use `-r` (recursive) option:

```
sudo cp -r -i /media/owner/ESD-USB/mysql /var/lib/
```

This will create (or overwrite the content of) `/var/lib/mysql/` directory. You probably want it that way. Otherwise, if you want to copy the files from within `mysql` to `/var/lib/` (i.e. not to `/var/lib/mysql/`) you may use:

```
sudo cp -i /media/owner/ESD-USB/mysql/* /var/lib/
```